# Big O for multi loops

Tags: java, big-o

```
    count++;
    count++;
    count++;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                count++;
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
    count++;
    return count;
}
```

Trying to get the Big O of this coding. Struggling to understand how the loops interact. When I run it, I get n = 25 count = 898960. I've tried O(n)^5+9 all the way to O(n)^5/n

All other examples of this problem don't deal with I is used in the second loop (I*I) and j is used in the third loop

Comment: I think it's n^4, but I just eyeballed it and didn't check my work.

Comment: n^4 is 390,625 which is a bit more than half of what the program output. A big gap to make me think it's not

Comment: @Robert based on that `for (int i=0; i<n*n; i++)` should be `O(n)` which is not true. Loop condition is also important.

Comment: This formula can be bounded by O(n^4logn) perfectly. I am not sure about O(n^4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost always the best way to compute complexities of kinda loops should be done by making use of sigma notation.

[image]

P.S. I don't write necessary +1s in the formulas since it is not important for Big-O notation and doesn't affect max power which is `5`.

Comment: So we both got it right at the end! Why I didn't put it in a mathematical notation is that most of the programmers would actually not understand it :)

Comment: @Siavas `most of the programmers would actually not understand it` means that they should learn.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is `O(n^5)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // 0 to n -> O(n)
    for(int j = 0; j < i*i; j++) // 0 to n * n -> O(n^2) repeated n times -> O(n^3)
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) // 0 to n * n -> O (n^2) repeated O(n^3) times -> O(n^5)
```

In the best case scenario, three nested loops would give you `O(n^3)`, but as you have the second loop repeat `(n^2)` times, that will square its complexity and of the third loop as well. So in a simple mathematical notation that will be: `(n) * (n * n) * (n * n) = n^5`.

Comment: Problem is I can not get this to conform with the outputted "operations". O^5 goes to '9,765,625' which is 10.86x the 898960. Maybe my coding is wrong in counting?

Comment: @Novabomb I am self-tough so I can be wrong on this but let me ask you a counterquestion. How do you think, what is "time" complexity of `for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) for (int j=1; j<=i; j++){count++;}`? In first iteration it will increment `count` once, then twice, and so on. So its value will be `1+2+3+..+N` which is `N*(a1+aN)/2` = `N(1+N)/2` = `N/2+N^2/2` but we still say that its complexity is `O(N^2)` because result depends *mostly* (for big N values) on `N^2`. If I understand correctly purpose of O(n) isn't to be *exact/precise* but to show us general "idea" of its *curve*.

Comment: Exactly @Pshemo, the same is taught at the university. Big O notation would give a general clue on how complex the algorithm is, but not necessarily how it would actually perform.

Comment: @pshemo I was taught that but expected the results to be within a certain range of the results. Being so so far off made me automatically doubt myself. In the end I had it right but just doubted